# having trouble with cakePHP Bake and one of the database tables

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model, cakephp-bake

I am using Bake to create models for my database tables.
I have run into a little problem.

I have 25 tables ....

I strated baking the models until for one of the database tables the bake started giving a name of it own to the model,file and class.

For example ,the table in database is named :  'risk_manager'

(It has association with other tables which i'm defining while baking)

However the model for this turns up as a file called "risk.php" and the class name is called "risk" (but it is mapped to the correct table.)

Why is this happening...?

Comment: Can you please show us the SQL you're using to define the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure if that's the reason, but Cake expects table names to be plural, so "`risk_managers`" would be correct.

Comment: You are correct... And i have made the changes but the problem persists